# Start a process on a specific core/CPU?

Tags: linux

Is there a way to specify that an application run on a specific core on linux? Like for example:

```
firefox core0
```

Or something that'd function that way conceptually?

Comment: You should explain why you want to do that. The kernel and its scheduler is much better than you at choosing cores.

Comment: Since the question is closed I commend here for who that interest in this topic. In  `man 2 sched_setaffinity` you can find a great example and it works perfectly. For command-line tool: `tastset` and book: `Linux System Programming` by Robert Love. Chapter 6.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/483824/run-program-with-only-1-cpu-core

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make use of `taskset` from `util-linux`

`cpuset` also seems to be working. I'm not too familiar with it though. [cpuset](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html)

Comment: Link is broken "How to run program or process on specific CPU cores on Linux"

Answer (score 5):

Using `taskset`, which is a part of `util-linux` package you can do this. For details check [here](http://xmodulo.com/2013/10/run-program-process-specific-cpu-cores-linux.html)

Using `taskset` you can assign a running process to particular CPU core. For example, to assign a process to CPU core 0 and 4, do the following.

```
taskset -p 0x11 <pid>
```