# Will node.js make use of multiple cores?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have a Ubuntu 16 machine with two Node.js web sites, ie two Node.js applications listening on different ports. If the CPU has more than one core available, will the two web sites be running their threads on different cores? Is there anything I must do to make them always run on separate cores?

Curently, I launched my applications simply using:

```
cd app1
nodejs ./server.js
cd ../app2
nodejs ./server.js
```

Comment: Ultimately, this is a question about how Ubuntu/Linux schedules threads/processes.

Comment: Maybe you can try to run them on [specific core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21153084/5156280) with _taskset_ or _cpuset_.

Comment: Doing it this way you are launching 2 node applications in 2 different cores, unless you were using cluster.

Answer (score 1):

As can be found in the [official node.js documentation][1]:

> A single instance of Node.js runs in a single thread. To take
>   advantage of multi-core systems the user will sometimes want to launch
>   a cluster of Node.js processes to handle the load.

So the answer to your questions are:

> will the two web sites be running their threads on different cores?

Yes

> Is there anything I must do to make them always run on separate cores?

No, is the node.js default behaviour.

Comment: The Node.js _process_ uses multiple threads. I also think it's possible that multiple Node.js processes get scheduled to run on the same core.

Comment: That's not true, please read the node.js documentation I referenced in the response.

Comment: You should read up on how the event loop is implemented (using multiple worker threads) in Node.js. If you don't believe me, fire up `top` or something similar and take a look at the # of threads that are associated with a `node` process.

Comment: In my experience running node.js servers for years, and they used as many cores as instances you launch, is not a belief question. But don't be confused about number of threads, and how many processors are being used, is not the same. as test you can launch a heavy task and with a top/ntop see how only one core goes to 100%. Hope this helps.

Comment: There is only one thread that runs JS code, but Node.js is more than that. `libuv`, which is used to implement the event loop, starts 4 I/O worker threads by default (tunable through `$UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE`) to handle network I/O, for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to prove. Fact of the matter is: a Node.js process consists of multiple threads (which, in the case of Linux, can be run on different cores). One of those threads is dedicated to JS code, which is typically what's meant with _"Node.js is single-threaded"_: you can't manage threads from JS ([yet](https://webkit.org/blog/7846/concurrent-javascript-it-can-work/)). More info on how the Node.js event loop works: http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

Comment: It's an off-topic question, like I said in my comment.